# JPAAnnotationProcessor processing files excluded by ant

Tags: ant, querydsl

I'm not sure whether this is a question concerning ant or the *JPAAnnotationProcessor* of QueryDSL.

I have a following target in the build.xml:

```
<target name="querydsl" depends="-prepare">
   <javac srcdir="${src.java.home}" classpathref="compile.classpath" includeantruntime="false">
      <include name="de/foo/bar/database/model/**"/>
      <compilerarg value="-proc:only"/>      
      <compilerarg value="-processor"/>
      <compilerarg value="com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"/>
      <compilerarg value="-s"/>
      <compilerarg value="${src.java.generated.home}"/>
   </javac>
</target>
```

and I only want the classes located under de/foo/bar/database/model/ to be processed.

When I execute `ant querydsl` I get compile errors from classes that are located outside of the ant include parameter, e.g.

```
[javac] C:\projects\main\cxlBackend\src\main\java\de\foo\bar\database\service\company\CompanyServiceImpl.java:96: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class QAccount
```

I tried to explicitly exclude this class with

```
<exclude name="de/foo/bar/database/service/company/CompanyServiceImpl.java"/>
```

but I'm still getting the same error.

Edit: At the beginning, ant writes out:

```
[javac] Compiling 267 source files
```

That's the exact number of classes in the de/foo/bar/database/model/ directory.

Comment: These are not compilation errors, just warnings, do the files still get generated without the include element?

Comment: I know the compilation goes on and succeeds and the messages only appear after having cleaned the generated Q-classes but they are confusing and bloat the output. We'd love to get rid of them. :) What reason does JPAAnnotationProcessor have to look outside of the specified directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after an upgrade to Java 7 (from Java 6).

Answer (score 1):

These warnings are printed by javac since the Q-classes are not yet available.

According to the [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) docs you can suppress the warnings with the -nowarn flag.

Comment: But why is ant (or the querydsl processor) trying to compile a class that is outside the specified directory or even explicitly excluded? None of the classes in the model directory includes CompanyServiceImpl.java and yet something tries to compile it.

Comment: <javac ... nowarn="true" ...> didn't help.